# Youtube Api V3 Search - Remove first char (char ¿) on video descriptions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i have a problem whith the youtube api v3 search.
the query return all the videos but in the objects, snippets, the description los his first char (char ¿)

For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51Gj1JSPafs

**Description:**

**¿**Estás pensando en tener un perro? Entonces no te pierdas estos consejos facilitados por la Médica Veterinaria María Belén Villar, Responsable de comunicación Técnica de Labyes, para darle lo mejor al nuevo integrante de la familia.

**Api description return**

**E**stás pensando en tener un perro? Entonces no te pierdas estos consejos facilitados por la Médica Veterinaria María Belén Villar, Responsable de comunicación Técnica de Labyes, para darle lo mejor al nuevo integrante de la familia.

any idea ?

thanks !

Comment: i use de regionCode in the query, but not change anything in the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is a bug or just a normal with the [`search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method.

But, if you use the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get the specific video using **id=51Gj1JSPafs**. You will get here the whole description of the video with the (**char ¿**).

**"¿Estás pensando en tener un perro? Entonces no te pierdas estos consejos facilitados por la Médica Veterinaria María Belén Villar, Responsable de comunicación Técnica de Labyes......"**

I made some test with my videos. And it seems that the `search.list` method will not get any special character in the beginning of the word in the description.

So I have these two videos that have a description of **#IDOL** and **@kobe**. 
If I use the `search.list`, using my channel, I only get the description **IDOL** and **kobe**. But if I use the `video.list`, and use the video specific videoId, I get the whole or original description **#IDOL** and **@kobe**.

Here is my **channelId=UCTEAryTk0JGFSLNZ0tBIw2w** if you want to try to test.

Comment: you're welcome, just use the video.list to get the original video description :)